# limit amount of friends to 12 shown in a box?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i have a box which displays friends of a user, however, it shows them all and stretched off the canvas of the app. I have them in a table in the box, is there anyway to limit the amount shown to 12 random friends?

this is my code to display friends:

```
if ($user) {
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

echo '<table>';
foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<div class="pic">';
    echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture"/>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<font color="white">','<div class="picName">'.$value["name"].'</div>','</font>';
    echo '</td>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, for instance, use the [`break`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) statement to exit the loop. Use it like this:

```
if ($user) {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

$counter = 1;

echo '<table>';
foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<div class="pic">';
    echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture"/>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<font color="white">','<div class="picName">'.$value["name"].'</div>','</font>';
    echo '</td>';

    if ($counter >= 12) {
        break;
    }
    $counter = $counter + 1;
}
echo '</table>';
}
```

A more advanced approach would make use of the [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function, which modifies arrays. To only get at most 12 elements, starting at position 0, of `$friends['data']` into the `foreach` loop, you would write:

```
// your code...
foreach (array_slice($friends["data"], 0, 12) as $value) {
    // your code...
```

Comment: It certainly is. I wanted to state both approaches to help teach something about the language. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FQL to make an SQL-like query that can limit and randomize the records returned.
Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 12;
```

To use FQL with the PHP SDK, use this format:

```
$facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => $fql
));
```

, `$fql` being the query.

Check out the [Technical Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/) and the [Table Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) of FQL.